# Get instance of subtype of a model with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an `Animal` model, based on the `animal` table.

This table contains a `type` field, that can contain values such as *cat* or *dog*.

I would like to be able to create objects such as :

```
class Animal extends Model { }
class Dog extends Animal { }
class Cat extends Animal { }
```

Yet, being able to fetch an animal like this :

```
$animal = Animal::find($id);
```

But where `$animal` would be an instance of `Dog` or `Cat` depending on the `type` field, that I can check using `instance of` or that will work with type hinted methods. The reason is that 90% of the code is shared, but one can bark, and the other can meow.

I know that I can do `Dog::find($id)`, but it's not what I want : I can determine the type of the object only once it was fetched. I could also fetch the Animal, and then run `find()` on the right object, but this is doing two database calls, which I obviously don't want.

I tried to look for a way to "manually" instantiate an Eloquent model like Dog from Animal, but I could not find any method corresponding. Any idea or method I missed please ?

Comment: @B001ᛦ Of course, my Dog or Cat class is going to have corresponding interfaces, I don't see how it helps here ?

Comment: @ClmentM Looks like one to many polymorphic relationship https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-polymorphic-relations

Comment: @vivek_23 Not really, in this case it helps to filter comments of a given type, but you already know that you want comments in the end. Doesn't apply here.

Comment: @ClmentM I think it does. Animal can be either Cat or Dog. So, when you retrieve the animal type from animal table, it would give you an instance of either Dog or Cat depending upon what is stored in the database. The last line there says _The commentable relation on the Comment model will return either a Post or Video instance, depending on which type of model owns the comment._

Comment: @vivek_23 I dived more into the documentation and gave it a try, but Eloquent is based on actual column with `*_type` name to determine the subtype model. In my case I really have only one table, so while it's a nice feature, not in my case.

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34700373/laravel-5-dynamically-create-eloquent-models

Answer (score 9):

**As the OP stated inside his comments:** The database design is already set and therefore Laravel's [Polymorphic Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships) seems not to be an option here.

I **like the answer of Chris Neal** because I had to do something similar recently (writing my own Database Driver to support Eloquent for dbase/DBF files) and gained a lot experience with the internals of Laravel's Eloquent ORM.

I've added my personal flavour to it to make the code more dynamic while keeping an explicit mapping per model.

Supported features which I quickly tested:

- `Animal::find(1)` works as asked in your question
- `Animal::all()` works as well
- `Animal::where(['type' => 'dog'])->get()` will return `AnimalDog`-objects as a collection
- Dynamic object mapping per eloquent-class which uses this trait
- Fallback to `Animal`-model in case there is no mapping configured (or a new mapping appeared in the DB)

Disadvantages:

- It's rewriting the model's internal `newInstance()` and `newFromBuilder()` entirely (copy and paste). This means if there will be any update from the framework to this member functions you'll need to adopt the code by hand.

I hope it helps and I'm up for any suggestions, questions and additional use-cases in your scenario. Here are the use-cases and examples for it:

```
class Animal extends Model
{
    use MorphTrait; // You'll find the trait in the very end of this answer

    protected $morphKey = 'type'; // This is your column inside the database
    protected $morphMap = [ // This is the value-to-class mapping
        'dog' => AnimalDog::class,
        'cat' => AnimalCat::class,
    ];

}

class AnimalCat extends Animal {}
class AnimalDog extends Animal {}
```

And this is an example of how it can be used and below the respective results for it:

```
$cat = Animal::find(1);
$dog = Animal::find(2);
$new = Animal::find(3);
$all = Animal::all();

echo sprintf('ID: %s - Type: %s - Class: %s - Data: %s', $cat->id, $cat->type, get_class($cat), $cat, json_encode($cat->toArray())) . PHP_EOL;
echo sprintf('ID: %s - Type: %s - Class: %s - Data: %s', $dog->id, $dog->type, get_class($dog), $dog, json_encode($dog->toArray())) . PHP_EOL;
echo sprintf('ID: %s - Type: %s - Class: %s - Data: %s', $new->id, $new->type, get_class($new), $new, json_encode($new->toArray())) . PHP_EOL;

dd($all);
```

which results the following:

```
ID: 1 - Type: cat - Class: App\AnimalCat - Data: {"id":1,"type":"cat"}
ID: 2 - Type: dog - Class: App\AnimalDog - Data: {"id":2,"type":"dog"}
ID: 3 - Type: new-animal - Class: App\Animal - Data: {"id":3,"type":"new-animal"}

// Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1418
//  #items: array:2 [
//    0 => App\AnimalCat {#1419
//    1 => App\AnimalDog {#1422
//    2 => App\Animal {#1425
```

And in case you want you use the `MorphTrait` here is of course the full code for it:

```
<?php namespace App;

trait MorphTrait
{

    public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false)
    {
        // This method just provides a convenient way for us to generate fresh model
        // instances of this current model. It is particularly useful during the
        // hydration of new objects via the Eloquent query builder instances.
        if (isset($attributes['force_class_morph'])) {
            $class = $attributes['force_class_morph'];
            $model = new $class((array)$attributes);
        } else {
            $model = new static((array)$attributes);
        }

        $model->exists = $exists;

        $model->setConnection(
            $this->getConnectionName()
        );

        $model->setTable($this->getTable());

        return $model;
    }

    /**
     * Create a new model instance that is existing.
     *
     * @param array $attributes
     * @param string|null $connection
     * @return static
     */
    public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
    {
        $newInstance = [];
        if ($this->isValidMorphConfiguration($attributes)) {
            $newInstance = [
                'force_class_morph' => $this->morphMap[$attributes->{$this->morphKey}],
            ];
        }

        $model = $this->newInstance($newInstance, true);

        $model->setRawAttributes((array)$attributes, true);

        $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());

        $model->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);

        return $model;
    }

    private function isValidMorphConfiguration($attributes): bool
    {
        if (!isset($this->morphKey) || empty($this->morphMap)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (!array_key_exists($this->morphKey, (array)$attributes)) {
            return false;
        }

        return array_key_exists($attributes->{$this->morphKey}, $this->morphMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity. Does this also work with Animal::all()  Is the resulting collection a mixture of 'Dogs' and 'Cats'?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild pretty good question! I tested it locally and added it to my answer. Seems to work as well :-)

Comment: modifying the laravel's built in function isn't correct way. All changes will loose once we update the laravel and it will mess up everything. Be aware.

Comment: Hey Navin, thank you for mentioning this but it‘s already clearly stated as disadvantage inside my answer. Counter question: What is the correct way then?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the Polymorphic Relationships in Laravel as explained in [Official Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships). Here is how you can do that.

Define the relationships in the model as given

```php
class Animal extends Model{
    public function animable(){
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Dog extends Model{
    public function animal(){
        return $this->morphOne('App\Animal', 'animable');
    }
}

class Cat extends Model{
    public function animal(){
        return $this->morphOne('App\Animal', 'animable');
    }
}
```

Here you'll need two columns in the **`animals`** table, first is **`animable_type`** and another is **`animable_id`** to determine the type of model attached to it at runtime.

You can fetch the Dog or Cat model as given,

```php
$animal = Animal::find($id);
$anim = $animal->animable; //this will return either Cat or Dog Model
```

After that, you can check the `$anim` object's class by using **`instanceof`**.

This approach will help you for future expansion if you add another animal type (i.e fox or lion) in the application. It will work without changing your codebase. This is the correct way to achieve your requirement. However, there is no alternative approach to achieve polymorphism and eager loading together without using a polymorphic relationship. If you don't use a **Polymorphic relationship**, you'll end up with more then one database call. However, if you have a single column that differentiates the modal type, maybe you have a wrong structured schema. I suggest you improve that if you want to simplify it for future development as well.

Rewriting the model's internal **`newInstance()`** and **`newFromBuilder()`** isn't a good/recommended way and you have to rework on it once you'll get the update from framework.

Comment: In the comments of the question he said, that he only has one table and the polymorphic features are not usable in the case of OP.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Then it won't be possible to eager load the relationship with eloquent and he will always pass through more than one database calls.

Comment: I'm just stating, what the given scenario is like. I personally would also use Polymorphic Relationships ;)

Comment: @shock_gone_wild That's correct :-) However, You may probably know that it's the only way. There is no workaround to eager load.

Comment: @KiranManiya thank you for your detailed answer. I'm interested in more background. Can you elaborate why (1) the questioners database model is wrong and (2) extending public/protected member functions isn't good/recommended?

Comment: @ChristophKluge, You already know. (1)DB model is wrong in the context of laravel design patterns. If you want to follow the design pattern defined by laravel, you should have DB schema according to it. (2) It's a framework internal method you have suggested to override. I won't do it if I ever face this issue. Laravel framework has built-in polymorphism support so why don't we use that rather re-inventing the wheel? You gave a good clue in the answer but I never preferred code with disadvantage instead we can code something that helps to simplify future expansion.

Comment: But... the whole question is not about Laravel Design patterns. Again, we have a given scenario (Perhaps the database is created by an external Application). Everyone will agree that polymorphism would be the way to go if you build from scratch. In fact your answer does technically not answer the original question.

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Thanks for pointing that out. I just put my thoughts as a post. I know it's not about design pattern but we should follow it.

Comment: @KiranManiya ok I see where you are coming from, which is totally valid and no offense from my side. I would perhaps make it very clear that this is the "laravel" way - which derives from the question. Thank you for giving heads up on my question. Small sidenote on (2) In my opinion overriding is a totally valid case. It's a core concept of OOP. If the framework would not allow this, then they could make it private right? Perhaps there was a valid reason for it.. who knows.. many brains, many ideas and solutions! :-)

Comment: @ChristophKluge Your sidenote is valid and I also believe in that. It's valid to override it in a modal (as OOP allows :-) ) but I gave high priority to laravel way.

Answer (score 5):

I think you could override the `newInstance` method on the `Animal` model, and check the type from the attributes and then init the corresponding model.

```php
    public function newInstance($attributes = [], $exists = false)
    {
        // This method just provides a convenient way for us to generate fresh model
        // instances of this current model. It is particularly useful during the
        // hydration of new objects via the Eloquent query builder instances.
        $modelName = ucfirst($attributes['type']);
        $model = new $modelName((array) $attributes);

        $model->exists = $exists;

        $model->setConnection(
            $this->getConnectionName()
        );

        $model->setTable($this->getTable());

        $model->mergeCasts($this->casts);

        return $model;
    }
```

You'll also need to override the `newFromBuilder` method.

```php
    /**
     * Create a new model instance that is existing.
     *
     * @param  array  $attributes
     * @param  string|null  $connection
     * @return static
     */
    public function newFromBuilder($attributes = [], $connection = null)
    {
        $model = $this->newInstance([
            'type' => $attributes['type']
        ], true);

        $model->setRawAttributes((array) $attributes, true);

        $model->setConnection($connection ?: $this->getConnectionName());

        $model->fireModelEvent('retrieved', false);

        return $model;
    }
```

Comment: I don't geht how this works. Animal::find(1) would throw an error: "undefined index type" if you call Animal::find(1). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @shock_gone_wild Do you have a column named `type` in the database?

Comment: Yes, i have. But the $attributes array is empty if I do a dd($attritubutes). Which does perfectly make sense. How do you use this in a real example?

Answer (score 5):

If you really want to do this, you could use the following approach inside your Animal model.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Animal extends Model
{

    // other code in animal model .... 

    public static function __callStatic($method, $parameters)
    {
        if ($method == 'find') {
            $model = parent::find($parameters[0]);

            if ($model) {
                switch ($model->type) {
                    case 'dog':
                        return new \App\Dog($model->attributes);
                    case 'cat':
                        return new \App\Cat($model->attributes);
                }
                return $model;
            }
        }

        return parent::__callStatic($method, $parameters);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think I know what you're looking for. Consider this elegant solution which uses Laravel query scopes, see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#query-scopes for additional information:

#### Create a parent class that holds shared logic:

```php
class Animal extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model
{
    const TYPE_DOG = 'dog';
    const TYPE_CAT = 'cat';
}
```

#### Create a child (or multiple) with a global query scope and a `saving` event handler:

```php
class Dog extends Animal
{
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::addGlobalScope('type', function(\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('type', self::TYPE_DOG);
        });

        // Add a listener for when saving models of this type, so that the `type`
        // is always set correctly.
        static::saving(function(Dog $model) {
            $model->type = self::TYPE_DOG;
        });
    }
}
```

(same applies to another class `Cat`, just replace the constant)

The global query scope acts as a default query modification, such that the `Dog` class will always look for records with `type='dog'`.

Say we have 3 records:

```
- id:1 => Cat
- id:2 => Dog
- id:3 => Mouse
```

Now calling `Dog::find(1)` would result in `null`, because the default query scope will not find the `id:1` which is a `Cat`. Calling `Animal::find(1)` and `Cat::find(1)` will both work, although only the last one gives you an actual Cat object.

The nice thing of this setup is that you can use the classes above to create relations like:

```php
class Owner
{
    public function dogs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Dog::class);
    }
}
```

And this relation will automatically only give you all the animals with the `type='dog'` (in the form of `Dog` classes). The query scope is automatically applied.

In addition, calling `Dog::create($properties)` will automatically set the `type` to `'dog'` due to the `saving` event hook (see https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#events).

Note that calling `Animal::create($properties)` does not have a default `type` so here you need to set that manually (which is to be expected).

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way yet is to make method in Animal class

```
public function resolve()
{
    $model = $this;
    if ($this->type == 'dog'){
        $model = new Dog();
    }else if ($this->type == 'cat'){
        $model = new Cat();
    }
    $model->setRawAttributes($this->getAttributes(), true);
    return $model;
}
```

Resolving model

```
$animal = Animal::first()->resolve();
```

This will return instance of class Animal, Dog or Cat depending on model type

Answer (score -2):

Although you are using Laravel, in this case, I think you should not stick to Laravel short-cuts.

This problem you are trying to solve is a classic problem that many other languages/frameworks solve using Factory method pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

If you want to have your code easier to understand and with no hidden tricks, you should use a well-known pattern instead of hidden/magic tricks under the hood.